# Why does browsers (who visited the side before) load the old version of my website?

Tags: javascript, html

I made some new features/tweaks to my HTML, CSS, and JS. I uploaded the new files to my web host, and I couldn't see the changes on the website. I tried to reload my browser with CMD + SHIFT + R (Hard Reload) and I could see the changes!!
My question is:
How can I show the current website without having to clear web data every time, as that would be pretty time consuming on phones?
Thank's Y'all!

Comment: Browsers cache GET responses. You can change your URLs to include "nonce" parameters to make the URLs different, or you can use HTTP cache headers to control cacheing behavior.

Comment: Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: Or you can simply clear cache from browser. There are simple extensions  - one button hit that will do that and reload page with changes...

Comment: @Pointy Nice! But wouldn't the nonce param overwrite the localstorage each time loading, as it is "a new website"?

Comment: local storage is stored per origin, not based on cache

Comment: @Pointy Thanks!! But the " <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="No-Cache">" doesn't seem to work. Am i doing i right?